# Runtime command doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, command, runtime, lpt

My command is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c copy /b D:\\MeAgent\\Reports\\receipt.hex lpt2:");
System.out.println("test");
```

In the console comes the "test", but the command is not executed and it comes no errormessage :(

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't escape the last backslash.

**Edit - now you've fixed the obvious**

When you call exec you spawn a Process.  You need to wait for that process to finish.

What you've got here is a race condition - i.e. your code is completing before the process executes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: I did it, I wrote it only false here :(

Comment: It dosent work :( 
I have tried it with a "while loop", with "wait" and
try {
            Process p = null;
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Can you use a javadoc link from Java 7?